# NSIS install path validation

Tags: nsis, electron-builder

I want to validate the installation path selected by the user. I can't figure out how to check that so it will look like this:

- You can't select a path with spaces (except Program Files)
- When you click "Install" then it will prompt the error saying that you have to change the installation directory

For now I have this:

```
  Function StrStr
  Exch $1 ; st=haystack,old$1, $1=needle
  Exch    ; st=old$1,haystack
  Exch $2 ; st=old$1,old$2, $2=haystack
  Push $3
  Push $4
  Push $5
  StrLen $3 $1
  StrCpy $4 0
  ; $1=needle
  ; $2=haystack
  ; $3=len(needle)
  ; $4=cnt
  ; $5=tmp
  loop:
    StrCpy $5 $2 $3 $4
    StrCmp $5 $1 done
    StrCmp $5 "" done
    IntOp $4 $4 + 1
    Goto loop
  done:
  StrCpy $1 $2 "" $4
  Pop $5
  Pop $4
  Pop $3
  Pop $2
  Exch $1
FunctionEnd

Function .onVerifyInstDir
Push "$INSTDIR"
Push " "
Call StrStr
Pop $0
StrCpy $0 $0 1
StrCmp $0 " " 0 +2
  Abort
FunctionEnd
```

It refuses to install while there is any space in the path. I need to modify this so Program Files will be the only exception for that rule. Also, printing error message would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This restriction makes no sense to me. Some legacy applications can't handle spaces in the path but that of course also includes the Program Files folder (although the `progra~1` hack can be used as a workaround **if** short name generation is active).

NSIS does not have a specific way to display a error/warning message directly on the page but you can change existing text in the UI and/or display a balloon.

```
!include WinMessages.nsh
!define /IfNDef EM_SHOWBALLOONTIP 0x1503
!define /IfNDef EM_HIDEBALLOONTIP 0x1504

!define DIRPAGE_CHANGETEXT ; Remove this line to disable the text change
!define DIRPAGE_BALLOON    ; Remove this line to disable the balloon
Function .onVerifyInstDir
    FindWindow $9 "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT
!ifdef DIRPAGE_CHANGETEXT
    GetDlgItem $3 $9 1006 ; IDC_INTROTEXT
    LockWindow on
!endif
    StrCpy $1 0
    loop:
        StrCpy $2 $InstDir 1 $1
        StrCmp $2 '' valid ; End of string
        StrCmp $2 ' ' found_space
        IntOp $1 $1 + 1
        Goto loop
valid:
!ifdef DIRPAGE_CHANGETEXT
    SetCtlColors $3 SYSCLR:18 SYSCLR:15
    SendMessage $3 ${WM_SETTEXT} "" "STR:$(^DirText)"
    LockWindow off
!endif
!ifdef DIRPAGE_BALLOON
    GetDlgItem $3 $9 1019
    SendMessage $3 ${EM_HIDEBALLOONTIP} "" "" ; Not required?
!endif
    Return
found_space:
    StrLen $1 "$ProgramFiles\"
    StrCpy $2 "$InstDir\" $1
    StrCmp $2 "$ProgramFiles\" valid
!ifdef DIRPAGE_CHANGETEXT
    SetCtlColors $3 ff0000 transparent
    SendMessage $3 ${WM_SETTEXT} "" "STR:Paths with spaces are not allowed, except for $ProgramFiles for some reason!"
    LockWindow off
!endif
!ifdef DIRPAGE_BALLOON
    GetDlgItem $3 $9 1019
    System::Call '*(&l${NSIS_PTR_SIZE},w "Bad path!", w "Spaced not allowed in path!",p 3)p.r2'
    SendMessage $3 ${EM_SHOWBALLOONTIP} "" $2 ; This will only work on XP and later (and you must use "XPStyle on")
    System::Free $2
!endif
    Abort
FunctionEnd

XPStyle on
Page Directory
```

The Next button is disabled when `Abort` is called inside `.onVerifyInstDir`. If you want to display a `MessageBox` when the user clicks next then you can't call `Abort` in `.onVerifyInstDir`, you will have to use the page leave function callback (where you have to verify the path again and maybe call `MessageBox`+`Abort`).